# How to wrap and indent long lines when using print()?

Tags: python, printing, indentation

I'm using Python to gather data from a Web service. The data itself is a list that will presented to users. I've managed it that it's printed out like:

```
( 1)  Example of strings
( 2)  Example 4
( 3)  Another Example
( 4)  Another Example 2
```

I'm using rjust (2) for the numbers. However, if the lines are very long, the printing will be like. The breaking width is the length of terminal (rxvt, gnome-terminal):

```
( 1)  Example of a very very very very long string and
that doesn't look fine
( 2)    Example of indented long line that is very very
long, example line
( 3)  Another Example
( 4)  Another Example of a very very long string and 
whatever here is
```

But what I've want is a print out like:

```
( 1)  Example of a very very very very long string and
      that doesn't look fine
( 2)    Example of indented long line that is very very
        long, example line
( 3)  Another Example
( 4)  Another Example of a very very long string and 
      whatever here is
```

Is there any ideas how to print the lines like above without breaking up the lines manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the textwrap module: http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html

```
 textwrap.fill(text, initial_indent='', subsequent_indent='      ')
```