# How to match long text with terminal width with separator?

Tags: python

My output text is long and I want to cut part and add "|" character

#### For 40 width, the output is look like this:

> [1] This is my text. A very long text.
>     | My text is going outside to terminal
>     | width. Look at the "|" character in
>     | the beginning of any part text.

#### and for 50 width, the output is look like this:

> [1] This is my text. A very long text. My text
>     | is going outside to terminal width. Look at
>     | the "|" character in the beginning of any part
>     | text.

So
 I'll print :

> [1] This is my text. A very long text. "\n" | My text is going outside to terminal "\n" | width. Look at the "|" character in "\n" | the beginning of any part text.

For 40 width

And I'll print :

> [1] This is my text. A very long text. My text "\n" | is going outside to terminal width. Look at "\n" | the "|" character in the beginning of any part "\n" | text.

For 50 width

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355061/how-to-wrap-and-indent-long-lines-when-using-print-in-python related?

Comment: @melpomene yes, thanks