# How to print between specific columns in screen in python?

Tags: python, printing, formatting

I want to print the abstract of a paper in the middle of Terminal screen of linux. The abstract is a continues long paragraph. I tried:

```
  print(colored(text.center(80), 'blue'))
```

but since the string is long it still occupy the whole width of screen, while I want to justify the text between say columns 10 to 70 ( for 80 columns screen)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap and indent long lines when using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355061/how-to-wrap-and-indent-long-lines-when-using-print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textwrap` module:

```
import textwrap
abstract = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
abstract = "\n".join(textwrap.wrap(abstract, 60)) # wrap at 60 characters
print(textwrap.indent(abstract, " "*10)) # indent with 10 spaces
```